# useQuery hook vs queryClient.fetchQuery, when to prefer one over the other

Tags: react-query

`queryClient.fetchQuery` can be used in place of `useQuery` hook provided by react-query. Any guidelines, best practices on in which scenario, one should be preferred over other.

One scenario might be where we want to conditionally fetch data. So, queryClient.fetchQuery looks more natural while useQuery hook not.

Is the above logic correct? Please advise on the best practise of using one over the other

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fetchQuery` is an imperative way to fetch data. You cannot call this during rendering, because it would be a side-effect and you cannot `await` the result. So you would need to spawn a useEffect.

The other difference is that `useQuery` creates a subscription to the queryKey, but `fetchQuery` does not. So if the data updates for some other reason (like a second component mounts and triggers a re-refetch of the query, or you refetch in the background because you focus the window and the query is stale), your component will *not* re-render and show the new data.

> One scenario might be where we want to conditionally fetch data.

This is where you want the `enabled` option of `useQuery`, so that you can `disable` your query for as long as the conditions are not met.

---

The bottom line is: The two are *not* interchangeable, I have almost never used `fetchQuery`. For components, always *useQuery*

Comment: I found it useful to use fetchQuery when I need to immediately use the returning data to make a decision, instead of differing the logic to a useEffect that listens to the changes returning from useQuery. 
For example, if I need to run server side validation as part of the form submit, and decide if the data should be submitted or not.

Not sure if there is a better way to achieve that then using fetchQuery

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good use case of fetchQuery (of React-Query) with react-router-dom which is explained by [@TkDodo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8405310/tkdodo) in this magnificent article https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-meets-react-router.

Briefly, you can use the power of react-router-dom's (after v6) start-fetching-before-rendering and takes this property further by adding the react-query's cache management and other good stuff on it.

It is a bit complicated and relatively more coding, but I guess the benefits are out of the discussion.