# How to tell React Query fetchQuery to make a new GET request and not used the already cached response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have the following function that makes a GET request for my user information and caches it using react query's fetchQuery so that every call after the first one does not make a GET request and instead just pulls the data from the cache.

```
export const getVegetables = async () =>
    await queryClient.fetchQuery(['getVegetables'], async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await request.get('/vegetables');

            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Failed to fetch vegetables');
        }
    });
```

The problem is that now I actually want to make a new GET request in order to check if the user data has changed, but calling `getVegetables()` pulls from the cache. How can I instruct fetchQuery to make a fresh GET request and not used the cache?

Comment: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-invalidation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification to your function will allow you to first invalidate the query (which will remove it from the cache).

```js
export const getSelf = async (skipCache = false) => {
    if(skipCache) { queryClient.invalidateQueries(['getSelf']); }
    
    return queryClient.fetchQuery(['getSelf'], async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await request.get('/users/me');

            // @todo: This sideloads a bunch of stuff, that we could cache
            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Failed to fetch user information');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of using fetchQuery, you can set cacheTime to 0 in query options, so every time you call it, it will suggest that cache is outdated and fetch fresh data, but I'd suggest you to use useQuery.

[Here you can read about difference between useQuery and fetchQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548117/usequery-hook-vs-queryclient-fetchquery-when-to-prefer-one-over-the-other)

The best way is to use useQuery hook and invalidate that query.

```
import { useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query'

// Get QueryClient from the context
const queryClient = useQueryClient()

queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['getSelf'] })
```

After invalidation, it will immediately fetch fresh data.

Answer (score 0):

`fetchQuery` will always fetch *unless* there is data in the cache that is considered `fresh`. This is determined by the `staleTime` setting.

`staleTime` defaults to `0` - which means "immediately stale". So the code you are showing that is calling `fetchQuery` should *always* fetch - unless you have a global `staleTime` set. You're not showing this in your code, but I guess this must be the reason. Note that `fetchQuery` doesn't know about `staleTime` being set by other observers (created by useQuery).

Now if you have a globally set `staleTime` and that is affecting `fetchQuery`, but you still want to always fetch, the best thing you can do is pass `staleTime: 0` directly to `fetchQuery`. Again, this is the default behaviour, so it's only necessary if you have a global staleTime set:

```
await queryClient.fetchQuery(
  ['getSelf'],
  async () => { ... },
  { staleTime: 0 }
)
```